# Can I move a Git Solution But Not My Credentials?

Tags: git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I am changing companies and I have created several apps to make my job easier, but they are all specific to the job I am leaving.  I want to give the source code to my manager who is also a good friend of mine.  I know I can just copy the directory making sure the `.git` folder is in there and it stays a git repo.  However I was using SourceTree (if it matters) and had all the repos in BitBucket (again, if it matters).  I would like them to have the full history, but not my credentials for BitBucket.  Will just moving them over to a shared network drive accomplish this or are the credentials part of the `.git` folder?

Comment: as far as I'm aware git repo's don't contain any credentials at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credentials are stored in your client and server, not in the repository itself. So yes, if you supply them the `.git` folder, that should do what you want.

One caveat: the `.git/config` file may contain some identifying information about you (but not authentication credentials). You could look over that and make sure to remove anything you don't want to leave around, like your name/email address.

Comment: Perfect!!!  Thank you.  I had seen some personal information in there but didn't want to touch it in case I broke the repository.